# using awk how to convert multi line record of fixed width to single line record

Tags: awk

I want to convert a fixed width file multiline record to singleline record . The file contain `4 fields`: 
**`date stamp` , `severity`, `error code` & `message type`.**  The record data can span across multiple lines based on the data in the field. For example 
`date stamp` field width is `10` characters - but the data  value is  `19` characters so it spread across two lines. first 10 character will be in first line  and next 9 characters is in second line

**field positions**

**date stamp  = 1 - 10** 
**severity   = 12- 17 [ the values can be error , info , warnings  so if the value is warning  the remaining data is placed in the second line from 12-17  ]**
**error_code = 18 -25** 
**message    = 26- 70**

There are no blank lines between records.

```
2014-02-21 INFO UTF8_INT  Starting execution of workflow
07:01:59                  [wf_router] in domain.

2014-02-21 error UTF8_INT  SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0
07:01:59                 (insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:):
                          ".Improved By Resting
                         [[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down
                         [[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).

2014-02-21 warni UTF8_INT  SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0
           ng              (insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:):
                          ".Improved By Resting
                         [[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down
                         [[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAHSR.png

Comment: Why is `UTF8_INT` misaligned in line 1, is that a typo? Why doesn't `warning` have its first 'n' in column 17 (your specs state 12-17, but this is more like 12-16)? With "no blank lines between records", how can you tell where a record ends? Or did I misunderstand your interpretation of the word 'between'? And last but not least, what is the desired output?

Comment: I have entered some sample data just to show the records . I want to convert this data to single line record format ,2014-02-21 07:01:59 ; INFO ; UTF8_INT ; Starting execution of workflow  [wf_router] in domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what you need (using GNU awk for various extensions):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="10 1 5 1 8 45" }

/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/ && (NR>1) { prtrec() }

{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        rec[i] = rec[i] $i
    }
}

END { prtrec() }

function prtrec() {
    n=split("1 3 5 6",f)
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",rec[f[i]])
        printf "%s%s", rec[f[i]], (i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }
    delete rec
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
2014-02-2107:01:59 INFO UTF8_INT Starting execution of workflow [wf_router] in domain.
2014-02-2107:01:59 error UTF8_INT SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0(insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:): ".Improved By Resting[[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down[[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).
2014-02-21 warning UTF8_INT SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0  (insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:): ".Improved By Resting[[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down[[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).
```

Just guessing at your desired output of course since you didn't post any in your question.

Comment: can you explain the logic of

Comment: function prtrec() {
    n=split("1 3 5 6",f)
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",rec[f[i]])
        printf "%s%s", rec[f[i]], (i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }

Comment: What do you think it does and I'll fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 0):

Though awk is designed to work with field separators (by default, whitespace), awk can read fixed-width files too. To retrieve a field with width *w*, starting at column *p* (where 1 is the left-most position in a line), use `substr($0, p, w)`. To accumulate column data across lines, you can simply use a variable per column.

```
{
    if (/[^ \t]/) {
        datetime = datetime " " trim(substr($0, 1, 10));
        severity = severity substr($0, 12, 5);
        errorcode = errorcode substr($0, 18, 8);
        message = message " " trim(substr($0, 26));
    }
    else {
        output();
        datetime = severity = errorcode = message = "";
    }
}

END {
    output();
}

function output() {
    if (datetime || severity || errorcode || message) {
        print trim(datetime) " ; " trim(severity) " ; " trim(errorcode) " ; " trim(message);
    }
}

function trim(s) {
    gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", s);
    return s;
}
```

Input (notice I sanitized the alignment of `UTF8_INT` on line 1):

```
2014-02-21 INFO  UTF8_INT Starting execution of workflow
07:01:59                  [wf_router] in domain.

2014-02-21 error UTF8_INT  SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0
07:01:59                 (insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:):
                          ".Improved By Resting
                         [[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down
                         [[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).

2014-02-21 warni UTF8_INT  SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0
           ng              (insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:):
                          ".Improved By Resting
                         [[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down
                         [[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).
```

Output:

```
2014-02-21 07:01:59 ; INFO ; UTF8_INT ; Starting execution of workflow [wf_router] in domain.
2014-02-21 07:01:59 ; error ; UTF8_INT ; SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0 (insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:): ".Improved By Resting [[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down [[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).
2014-02-21 ; warning ; UTF8_INT ; SQ_ff:Exchange: Rowdata: ( RowType=0 (insert) Src Rowid=1 TargIELD:Char.500:): ".Improved By Resting [[&lt;~a~&gt;Resting&lt;~a0~&gt;]]|Lying Down [[&lt;FNT&gt;&lt;!&gt;no Lying Down]]).
```

Notes:

- Since you did not answer all of my questions, I have no way of knowing whether the script matches all of your requirements.
- Assuming you need semicolon as a field separator in the output data, I wonder how you are going to handle the semicolons already present in the input data. Should I apply some kind of escaping?

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response .both of  your logics are correct